# I converted kivy python code to apk but after conversion and installation in my android it's getting crash when I open

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to convert my kivy code android apk but don't know why even after many tried and examples from tutorials and block it's getting crash each trial.

Here is my code:

```
`import os

os.environ['KIVY_NO_FILELOG'] = '1'  # disable file log
os.environ['KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG'] = '1'  # disable console log
os.environ['KIVY_LOG_LEVEL'] = 'critical'  # set log level to critical
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView
from kivy.core.window import Window
import datetime
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
import time
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

notes_save_path="/home/shiva/Desktop/Arabian_talk_scrappy/tryit/new_kivy_tries"
new_path="new_kivy_tries"
my_string="""

<MyNotepad>
    BoxLayout:
        name: 'my_notepad'
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput: 
            id: text_input
            background_color:'#D9F59C'
            background_active:''
            
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            size_hint: (1, None) 
            height:50
            Button:
                text: "save_note"
                font_size : '20sp'
                on_press: root.texter(text_input.text)
                bold: True
                background_color :'#808000'
                color: '#2ADFE8'

            Button:
                text: "Clear"
                font_size : '20sp'
                bold: True
                background_color :'#811322'
                color: '#2ADFE8'
                on_release: text_input.text = ""
"""
class MyNotepad(Screen):
    def texter(self, text):
        pass

class MY_NOTES(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(my_string)
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MyNotepad(name='my_notepad'))
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MY_NOTES().run()`
```

I even tried to do by checking logs from android studio as other blogs but still the same:
Here is buildozer.spec file and also collected logs too.You can check the .spec, main.py and logs file from here - [documnets](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QaO6FtHiIcW2qCE4E4pSG1kQflRrOqst?usp=share_link).

Comment: try to clear storage in device and then rebuild your app

Comment: But the storage is there already. I didn't get your exact point what's the point related to storage and crashing? Sorry if I'm wrong.